# Cartesian vector field to vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics

Ok so I have a given vector field in Cartesian coordinates, say 
\begin{align*}
\textbf{v}(x,y)=\frac{dx}{dt}\hat{\textbf{e}}_{1}+\frac{dy}{dt}\hat{\textbf{e}}_{2}
\end{align*}
Where $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ are functions of $x$ and $y$. I want to transform this into a polar coordinate field such as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{u}(r,\theta)=\frac{dr}{dt}\hat{\textbf{r}}+\frac{d\theta}{dt}\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}
\end{align*}
Where $dr/dt$ and $d\theta/dt$ are functions of $r$ and $\theta$I know the transformation.
\begin{align*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  dr/dt \\
  rd\theta/dt
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{cos}(\theta) & \text{sin}(\theta)\\
  -\text{sin}(\theta) & \text{cos}(\theta)
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  dx/dt \\
  dy/dt
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Can I just change my Cartesian vector field which is given in $x,y$ to $r,\theta$ and then apply that transformation matrix?

To be clear an example would be
\begin{align*}
\textbf{v}=(x,0)\\
\\
\text{which becomes}\\\\
\textbf{u}=(r\cos^{2}\theta,-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))
\end{align*}
Many thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of each $\hat{\textbf{r}},\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}$?

Comment: $\hat{\textbf{r}}=cos(\theta)\textbf{i}+sin(\theta)\textbf{j}$ is the unit vector in the radial direction and similarly for $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}$

Comment: are you requiring that $\hat\theta$ is orthonormal with $\hat{r}$ and oriented?

Comment: Yes, so $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}=-sin(\theta)\textbf{i}+cos(\theta)\textbf{j}$

Comment: last question before i could assemble an answer: are they $\{\hat{\boldsymbol e}_1,\hat{\boldsymbol e}_2\}$ and $\{\boldsymbol i,\boldsymbol j\}$ the same basis for you?

Comment: Yes, I think also my approach is correct and that my problem lay in being unsure about changing the cartesian-domained functions to polar-domained ones (I mean here the co-efficients of the basis vectors.

If I am wrong though I'd like to know as its currently in my dissertation

Answer (score 1):

if
$$\hat{\boldsymbol r}=\cos\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol e}_1+\sin\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol e}_2,$$
$$\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}=-\sin\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol e}_1+\cos\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol e}_2,$$
is the change of basis, then
we can solve to find: 
$$\hat{\boldsymbol e}_1=\cos\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol r}-\sin\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol \theta},$$ 
$$\hat{\boldsymbol e}_2=\sin\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol r}+\cos\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol \theta}.$$

So, for 
$\boldsymbol{\rm v}=\frac{dx}{dt}\hat{\boldsymbol e}_1+\frac{dy}{dt} \hat{\boldsymbol e}_2$
you will get
$$\boldsymbol{\rm v}=\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\cos\theta+\frac{dy}{dt}\sin\theta\right)\hat{\boldsymbol r}+
\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\cos\theta-\frac{dx}{dt}\sin\theta\right)\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}.$$

And if you wish to know the value of the functions $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ you only need to differentiate the coordinate change 
$$x=r\cos\theta\quad ,\quad y=r\sin\theta.$$